# Google Apps Script: add folder to folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I used a script to upload a folder with an image to a (parent?) folder. When I do it one time is does create a folder structure the right way. But, when I try it a second time, it creates a new folder in the root with the same name.

How can I change my code so that there is a parent folder where image folders will be added to?

Currently:

- First time: `/root/persons/test test@test.com/` (images inside this folder)
- New map second time: `/root/persons/test2 test2@test2.com/` (images inside this folder)

I want:
  `/root/persons/*(folders)/` (images inside this folder)

My code:

```
/* The script is deployed as a web app and renders the form */
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
// This is important as file upload fail in IFRAME Sandbox mode.
}

/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {

try {

/* Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved */
var dropbox = form.myName + " " + form.myEmail;
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

/* Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist */
if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  var firstLevelFolder = DriveApp.createFolder("Persons");
  var folder = firstLevelFolder.createFolder(dropbox);
}

/* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */
var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

/* Set the file description as the name of the uploader */
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

/* Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive */
return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

} catch (error) {

/* If there's an error, show the error message */
return error.toString();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't testing for the existence of the "Persons" folder, so every time you have a new user you re-create that folder. I suggest doing that earlier in the function, like this:

```js
/* Find the first level folder, create if the folder does not exist */
var firstLevelFolderName = "Persons";
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(firstLevelFolderName);
var firstLevelFolder = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(firstLevelFolderName);
```

Instead of an explicit `if..then..else` structure, note the use of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?` to keep the assignment in one statement. The same pattern can be used for any iterator being evaluated for "find vs create".

#### Updated script:

```js
/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {
  
  try {
    /* Find the first level folder, create if the folder does not exist */
    var firstLevelFolderName = "Persons";
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(firstLevelFolderName);
    var firstLevelFolder = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(firstLevelFolderName);
    
    /* Find the user-specific folder, create if the folder does not exist */
    var dropbox = form.myName + " " + form.myEmail;    /* Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved */    
    folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    var folder = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next() : firstLevelFolder.createFolder(dropbox); 
    
    /* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    
    /* Set the file description as the name of the uploader */
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
    
    /* Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive */
    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
    
  } catch (error) {
    
    /* If there's an error, show the error message */
    return error.toString();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to create a folder in an existing folder

```
const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1TukDeifX_nYZftbzODkUfD-hYlpx5TPg");
const folder1 = parentFolder.createFolder(Project + ", " + Date + ", " + Phone);
```